# How to run JMeter from Java for the remote (distrubted) application

Tags: jmeter, distributed

From GUI we can follow 

**Run -> Remote Start -> (select the ip, which we want to run remotely)**

From command line also we can specify **-R** flag to run remote jmeter application.

But here I am creating *jmx* file using *Java* and I want run this one from *Java* only. So, is there any way achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [DistributedRunner](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/engine/DistributedRunner.html) class like:

```
List<JMeterEngine> engines = new LinkedList<>();
Properties remoteProps = new Properties();
//set properties you want to send to remote clients here
DistributedRunner distributedRunner=new DistributedRunner(remoteProps);

List<String> hosts = new LinkedList<>();
//add your JMeter slaves here
hosts.add("remote_host_1");
hosts.add("remote_host_2");
distributedRunner.setStdout(System.out);
distributedRunner.setStdErr(System.err);
distributedRunner.init(hosts, testPlanTree);
engines.addAll(distributedRunner.getEngines());
distributedRunner.start();
```

For example of creating a JMeter test from Java code using [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/) check out [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) guide.

Also remember that JMeter is open source so you can look for implementation of this or that functionality directly in [JMeter's source code](http://jmeter.apache.org/svnindex.html).

Answer (score 0):

You must implement an interface [RemoteJMeterEngine](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/engine/RemoteJMeterEngine.html). Also, have a look at [RemoteJMeterEngineImpl](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/engine/RemoteJMeterEngineImpl.html) class for reference.

If you have tried running test locally trough Java, this should not be much more complicated to achieve.